# Make certain rows in R missing with probability x

Tags: r

I wish to make a certain number of rows missing with probability "X".

For example, take the `iris` data set, and append a new column to it with values from 0 to 1.

`data(iris)`

`iris <- iris %>% mutate(ind = runif(n = nrow(iris), 0, 1))`

Then for each row, each of the remaining variables `Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, Petal.Width, Petal.Length, Species` should be missing with probability corresponding to this new `ind` column

For example, say we have

```
set.seed(99)
data(iris)
iris <- iris %>% mutate(ind = runif(n = nrow(iris), 0, 1))
```

we get a table like so

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species         ind
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa 0.802761295
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa 0.230139103
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa 0.665336609
```

Then after running the code - in the first row Sepal.Length is NA with probability 0.802761295. Then Sepal.Width is missing with this probability, ..., then Species is missing with probability 0.802761295.

For the second row, Sepal.Length is missing with probability 0.230139103.

And so forth.

I have tried using a for loop and if statement to run this, but cannot help but feel there is a more efficient way going forward. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` to loop through the rows (or any dimension) of appropriate data structures (`data.frame`, `matrix`, etc).

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(99)
data(iris)
iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(ind = runif(n = nrow(iris), 0, 1)) 
res <- data.frame(t(apply(iris, 1, FUN = function(x) {
  x[which(runif(5) < x[6])] = NA
  x
})))
head(res)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species         ind
#> 1         <NA>        <NA>          1.4         0.2  setosa 0.584711852
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 0.113781675
#> 3         <NA>         3.2         <NA>        <NA>    <NA> 0.684264744
#> 4         <NA>        <NA>         <NA>        <NA>    <NA> 0.992508777
#> 5          5.0         3.6         <NA>        <NA>  setosa 0.534993585
#> 6         <NA>        <NA>         <NA>        <NA>    <NA> 0.966614064
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
iris[,1:5][matrix(runif(nrow(iris)*5), ncol = 5) < iris$ind] <- NA
```

It generates a matrix of uniformly distributed random numbers of dimension nrow(iris) x 5 and compares it to `iris$ind` (elements of the `iris$ind` vector are recycled in the comparison). Elements of `iris` corresponding to values lower than `iris$ind` are then set to `NA`.

```
# > head(iris)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species        ind
# 1           NA          NA          1.4         0.2  setosa 0.58471185
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 0.11378168
# 3          4.7          NA           NA          NA  setosa 0.68426474
# 4           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA> 0.99250878
# 5          5.0         3.6           NA          NA  setosa 0.53499358
# 6           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA> 0.96661406
```